# XQuery extract between two tags

Tags: xml, xquery, html-content-extraction

I am currently working on extracting data from `HTML`. I would like to extract the text between two `<p class="xfHeading">` tags.

```
         <p class="xfHeading"><b>XYZ:</b></p> 
            <p>asdfghjk</p>  
            <p>sdsdsd</p>  
            <p>asdvcvcfghjk</p>  

         <p class="xfHeading"><b>ABC:</b></p> 
            <P>fvgbhnjm</P>  

         <p class="xfHeading"><b>PQR:</b></p> 
            <ul> 

            </ul> 

         <p class="xfHeading"><b>MNO:</b></p> 
             <ul> 
                <li>jdjshdj</li>  
             </ul>
```

The **output** should be :

asdfghjk

sdsdsd

asdvcvcfghjk

One way to do this is :

```
/p[class="xfHeading"]/following-sibling::p[0]|/p[class="xfHeading"]/following-sibling::p[1]|/p[class="xfHeading"]/following-sibling::p[2]
```

or

```
/p[class="xfHeading"]/following-sibling::p[position()<4]
```

However since the content between  keeps on changing all the time I need a solution wherein the content between the two tags `<p class="xfHeading">` is extracted.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I updated my answer with a new suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
(//p[@class="xfHeading"])[1]
          /following-sibling::p
             [. << (//p[@class="xfHeading"])[2]]
                 /text()
```

**This means**: Select the text-node children of all `p` elements that are following siblings of the first `p` element in the document with `class` attribute having value of `xfHeading`, and that at the same time are preceding the second `p` element in the document with `class` attribute having value of `xfHeading`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: After your clarification, my suggestion is to use a [FLWOR](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xquery_flwor.html) expression such as the following. This looks for a `<p>` with the proper `<b>` tag contents based on the unique contents of that `<b>` tag, and returns the text of each `<p>` tag that is a sibling of it.

```
for $b in //p[class="xfHeading"]/b and $p in //p[class="xfHeading"]/p
    where $b/text() = "XYZ:"
        return p/text()
```

Note that the `//` is an XPATH construct, not a comment

**OLD ANSWER**: Without an example of what you'd like the resulting data to look like, answering the question is a bit tough. However, to select, for instance, the text inside a `<b>` tag, you'd do:

```
/p[class = "xfHeading"]/b/text()
```

In general, appending `text()` to the end of an expression returns the text inside the node in question.